# \n is getting appended at end of each line in xml response when using js2xml parser

Tags: node.js, js2xml

I have a requirement where I have to generate an xml as response. For this I am doing

responsebody = js2xmlparser.parse("XYZ",responsebody); in my code where I am actually preparing XML. responsebody till this line is actually appending some values from database. Did not want to post it here. I checked the response before this line which looks like below.

{ Del:
   [ { serial: 
       LineNo: null,
       SerialNo: '256691560502253916' }] }

After js2xmlparse("XYZ",responsebody) it becomes like below :

```
 "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n
<XYZ>\n    
    <Del>\n        
        <serial>\n            
            <LineNo>null</LineNo>\n
            <SerialNo>256691560502253916</SerialNo>\n
        </serial>\n
    </Del>\n
</XYZ>"
```

Any suggestions on how to not get those \n in response. The response that I posted here is from Postman.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Issue with PostMan and not your Code. 
Most likely to do with: [`github:postmanlabs/postman-app-support#5543`](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5543)